# Most common way to securely access a database

Tags: android, database, rest, web-services, security

I have an application with a user authentication and every user should be able to read the data from the database.
Like showing the data in a ViewTable or whatever.

Therefore I have to create a database connection. My problem is when I create it in my C# file I'm not feeling secure because somebody could readout the file with the user and password and so on...

So my idea was to write an api in php for example with a post request. In there are the user/password an the SQL Statement and the only thing I'm doing in the C# file is calling this api. My question is: Is this the common way to do so or is there a better and more secure way to handle such things.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly your question is. Do you want to protect your application ith authentication? Of course, your database should be protected by standard username/password authentication which all standard databases support.

Comment: @JurajMartinka I edited my question. I hope it's more understandable now :)

Comment: Stil don't completely understand. If you're worried about hardcoding credentials in source code then the standard way is to read db password from the environment (like external properties files and environment variables). That is however not perfect and thus some people prefer using more sophisticated solutions like https://www.vaultproject.io.